# Screenshot fail to store in ios devices

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use Screenshot code that works perfectly on pc, but not on ios devices.

typically ios devices wii ask for permission to assess the photos library.

but it didn't?

```
public IEnumerator CaptureScreen()
    {
        yield return null;

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + $"/Screenshot.png");
    }
```

I also use fellow code,it;s no work

```
byte[] pngShot = ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG(tex_transparent);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + $"/Screenshot{index}.png", pngShot);
```

Comment: @limserhane  i try it before, but the photo still no save in photolibrary  in ios device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Application.persitentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) is not the path for the library of the gallery app. You need to create a custom native solution or maybe get an asset from the [asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com/) to save images to the gallery.